# Protractor times out waiting for element that exists

Tags: angularjs, angular, protractor

I'm starting some tests in my Angular 2 application and in the first test I'm having some problems.

I want to test the login page, so I am trying to fill email. Here is my test code:

```
describe('login page', function() {
    it('should login', function() {

        browser.get('http://localhost:3000/#/login');

        element(by.css('.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-untouched')).sendKeys('test@test.com');

    });
});
```

My render HTML code is:

```
<form class="login-form mt-lg ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
   <!--template bindings={}-->
   <!--template bindings={}-->
   <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="email">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
   </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="btn-toolbar float-xs-right m-t-1">
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Log in</button>
    </div>
    <div class="float-xs-left m-t-1">
      <a class="mt help-block">Forgot your password?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The "original" HTML code is:

```
<form class="login-form mt-lg" (ngSubmit)="login($event)">
  <div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
  <div *ngIf="info" class="alert alert-info">{{info}}</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" [(ngModel)]="user.email" #email="ngModel">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Senha" [(ngModel)]="user.password" #password="ngModel">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="btn-toolbar float-xs-right m-t-1">
      <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Entrar</button>
    </div>
    <div class="float-xs-left m-t-1">
      <a class="mt help-block" (click)="modal.show()">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I execute the test the browser opens, the page fully loads but then it times out:

```
Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, .form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-untouched)
```

If I search for this selector in Chrome console it returns the expected element:

```
document.querySelector('.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-untouched')
```

The problem is when the browser opens I can see the page fully loaded and the input is there! And after 11 seconds (or so) the browser closes with the error message. I also tryed to increase timeout on configuration file:

```
allScriptsTimeout: 50000
```

But it still does not identify the element:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I figured it out. For some reason in Chrome console network tab there is a websocket request as "Pending" so apparently Pratractor keeps waiting this request to finish. This request has 101 HTTP status, I really don't know what it means but after a quick search I learned that it is suposed to be marked as "Pending" in Chrome console.

To solve this issue I prevent syncronization:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

And defined a timeout in configuration file:

```
allScriptsTimeout: 50000
```

And it worked!

Here is how the final code was:

```
describe('login page', function() {
    it('should login', function() {

        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

        browser.get('http://localhost:3000/#/login');

        element(by.css('.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-untouched')).sendKeys('test@test.com');

    });
});
```

If someone knows a better solution or how to avoid this "websocket" request please let me know.

Comment: From what I understand, preventing sync will lead to flaky tests. Did you find any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

The timeout occured because you have two elements with same classes so include the index as below

```
element(by.css('.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-untouched')[0]).sendKeys('test@test.com');
```

Update 1:

Try this

```
element(by.css('input[name=email]')).setAttribute('value','test@test.com').then((value: string) => {
            expect(value).toBe('test@test.com');
        });
```

Update 2 :

```
element(by.css('input[name=email]')).setAttribute('value','test@test.com').then((value: string) => {
                expect(value).toBe('test@test.com');
            });
                browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.not(
          ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element(by.css('input[name=email]')))))
          .then(() => screenshot('received value '));
      });
```

Comment: Nothing... Same problem:
Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
    While waiting for element with locator - Locator: undefined

Comment: It seems to be some syntax error on "value: string": E/launcher - Error: /var/www/Engine-Frontend/tests/login.spec.js:6 element(by.id('input[name=email]')).setAttribute('value','test@test.com').then((value: string) => {

Comment: remove the colon and string **: string** and give a try

Comment: Made some changes but I got this error: Failed: element(...).setAttribute is not a function

Comment: it is not id my bad its **by.css**

Comment: Same issue. It seems to be an syntax error on colon and =>. If I remove then() method it returns Failed: element(...).setAttribute is not a function

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try to select element by name instead?

```
element(by.name('email')).sendKeys("test@test.com");
element(by.name('password')).sendKeys("mypassword");
```

Comment: I did try, same issue.
Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
    While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, *[name="email"])

Comment: it seems to be according to the documentation http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy

Comment: Is possible to be something in the page that blocks this identification? I tested in the original layout and works there.

Answer (score 1):

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

The above code makes protractor not to wait for Angular promises. This will be used when we test non-angular web pages.

Here in your issue, you can just set or increase the getPageTimeout value in jasmineNodeOptions.

```
getPageTimeout: 50000
```

Comment: I agree with you, but it apparently keeps waiting for a response in a request with 101 HTTP status (that will be "processing" forever - as far as I research). That's why I ignored synchronization. I tryied your solution but it didn't worked. I'll check where this websocket request is made so I can do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

`browser.ignoreSynchronization` is deprecated.

Use...

```
describe('login page', function() {
it('should login', function() {

    browser.waitForAngularEnabled();

    browser.get('http://localhost:3000/#/login');

    element(by.css('.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-untouched')).sendKeys('test@test.com');

 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In our case the problem was in a super-long timeout. We had an autologout feature implemented with 16 hour timeout. Protractor calls `waitForAngular` function every time we execute any action. `waitForAngular` is waiting for two things: the unfinished http-requests and the unfinished timeouts. Check your code for those.

Answer (score 0):

`browser.get` returns a promise so to make sure DOM is loaded before selecting your element, you could do it like this :

```
browser.get(MY_URL).then(() => {

    // Your instructions to select and tests DOM elements

});
```